# Angular RxJS, push newly added item to the existing Observable Array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have 2 services.
RoomService -> Returns a list of existing rooms
NotificationService -> Returns a Server Sent Event (SSE) when a new room is added.

What I'm trying to do is

- Fetch all the existing rooms
- Await the SSE for room creation
- When SSE is received, add this new room to the list of existing rooms.

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
export class RoomListComponent {
  rooms$: Observable<Room[]> = this.roomService
    .getRooms()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((rooms) =>
        this.notificationService
          .getServerSentEvent<Room>()
          .pipe(concatMap((room) => [...rooms, room]))
      )
    );

  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private roomService: RoomService
  ) {}
}
```

But this results in error
`Type 'Observable<Room>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Room[]>'. Type 'Room' is missing the following properties from type 'Room[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2322)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like a job for the scan pipe operator to accumulate emissions

Comment: Andrew Allen gave you a nice answer.
But if you're intererested why you have this error, it's because you should use map instead of concatMap. ConcatMap would fit, if you returned observable from its lambda. If you're returning simple array you just use map.
But it still wouldn't work correctly, as it won't acucmulate all newly added rooms, just the most recent one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [scan](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) to accumulate all new rooms emitted from your `notificationService`

```
const initialRooms$ = roomService.getRooms();

const allNewRooms$ = notificationService.getServerSentEvent().pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []),
  startWith([])
);

// all rooms
combineLatest([initialRooms$, allNewRooms$])
  .pipe(map(([initialRooms, allNewRooms]) => [...initialRooms, ...allNewRooms]))
  .subscribe((arr) => console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)));
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dzyoft?file=index.ts)